# BFS implementation over adjacency matrix gives sysmalloc error

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, breadth-first-search, adjacency-matrix

I wrote a program to receive two integers ( n and x ), and then a n times n adjacency matrix. The program should output the distance between node x and every other node ( or otherwise 0 if it's the same node, and -1 if they're disjoint ).

So for instance, this:

```
6 3 
0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 
0 0 1 0 1 0 
1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0
```

Should give this as output:

```
2 3 1 0 1 -1
```

So the code below is working as expected for the example above:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(){
    int i, j, k, n, x, array[6][6], visited[6], result[6], counter;
    int queue[6], p, u;
    scanf("%i",&n);
    scanf("%i",&x);
    //array = malloc(sizeof(int*) * n);
    //visited = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    //queue = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    for(i=0;i<n;++i) visited[i] = 0;
    p = 0;
    u = 0;
    //for(i=0;i<n;++i) array[i] = malloc(sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<n;++i){
        for(j=0;j<n;++j){
            scanf("%i",&array[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;++i){
        k = x;
        visited[k] = 1;
        counter = 0;
        if(array[x][i] == 1) ++counter; 
        while(array[x][i] != 1){
            if(x == i) break;
            for(j=0;j<n;++j){
                if( array[k][j] == 1 && visited[j] == 0){
                    visited[j] = 1;
                    queue[u++] = j;
                }
            }       
            if(p != u) k = queue[p++];
            else break;
            if(k == i){
                break;
            }
            ++counter;
        }
        for(j=0;j<n;++j) visited[j] = 0;
        p = 0;
        u = 0;
        if(counter == n - 2) counter = -1;
        result[i] = counter;
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;++i) printf("%i ",result[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This is what I get:

```
user@user-NH4CU03:~$ gcc cidades2.c -o cidades2 && ./cidades2 < input.txt
2 3 1 0 1 -1
```

However, when I turn this code into its dynamic version, this is what I get:

> cidades2: malloc.c:2394: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top
>   (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE &&
>   prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) ==
>   0)' failed. Aborted (core dumped)

And here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(){
    int i, j, k, n, x, **array, *visited, *result, counter;
    int *queue, p, u;
    scanf("%i",&n);
    scanf("%i",&x);
    array = malloc(sizeof(int*) * n);
    visited = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    queue = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    for(i=0;i<n;++i) visited[i] = 0;
    p = 0;
    u = 0;
    for(i=0;i<n;++i) array[i] = malloc(sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<n;++i){
        for(j=0;j<n;++j){
            scanf("%i",&array[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;++i){
        k = x;
        visited[k] = 1;
        counter = 0;
        if(array[x][i] == 1) ++counter; 
        while(array[x][i] != 1){
            if(x == i) break;
            for(j=0;j<n;++j){
                if( array[k][j] == 1 && visited[j] == 0){
                    visited[j] = 1;
                    queue[u++] = j;
                }
            }       
            if(p != u) k = queue[p++];
            else break;
            if(k == i){
                break;
            }
            ++counter;
        }
        for(j=0;j<n;++j) visited[j] = 0;
        p = 0;
        u = 0;
        if(counter == n - 2) counter = -1;
        result[i] = counter;
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;++i) printf("%i ",result[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

So what's happening here? Valgrind said there's nothing wrong with this code.

Comment: When you run this in a debugger, what line does it crash out on?

Comment: `array[i] = malloc(sizeof(int));` you only allocate memory for one `int`.

Comment: @melpomene That was the issue. Problem solved.